# Specifying Multiplicity in a Visio Database (ERD) Diagram

Tags: microsoft-visio, erd, diagrams, symbols

Is there a way to manually edit the cardinality/multiplicity symbols on the end of a database ERD made in Visio? The category I'm using is in Visio 2003 under `Database -> Database Model Diagram`

I want to be able to go from something like this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

The second graphic was done by manually adding the numbers, but I would prefer to just do it in Visio. Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up your diagram, and goto  `Database` - `Options` - `Document...` on the menu bar. From there, access the `Relationship` tab.

You need to enable the `Cardinality` option, which (making an assumption here from your first diagram) you will probably have to disable the `Crows Feet` option to be able to use.

You set the numbers using the options within the `Database Properties` window/pane when editing the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

In visio 2013:
Right click the connector
Choose "Show multiplicity" and number boxes appear

You can do this in Chen's notation - you don't need Crows Foot.